# How to register an expo push notification device

Tags: push-notification, expo

I am trying out the Expo push notification service. I ran the [code in the overview](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/) by clicking on "Try this example on snack", then pointed my iPad to the QR code, which loaded the example in Expo Go. When I tap "Press to Send Notification" indeed I see a notification, all good.

Using the same token printed on the iPad app ("Your expo push token: ExponentPushToken[token-goes-here]") I tried calling the [Expo API](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications/) by running a curl command on my PC in order to trigger the push notification remotely with `HTTPS POST`, while keeping the app in the foreground:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send" -d '{
  "to": "ExponentPushToken[token-goes-here]",
  "title":"hallo",
  "body": "world"
}'
```

But I get:

```
{"data":{"status":"error","message":"\"ExponentPushToken[token-goes-here]\" is not a registered push notification recipient","details":{"error":"DeviceNotRegistered"}}}
```

Looking at the code for `sendPushNotification(expoPushToken)` I see it uses the same API with `fetch`:

```
// Can use this function below, OR use Expo's Push Notification Tool-> https://expo.io/notifications
async function sendPushNotification(expoPushToken) {
  const message = {
    to: expoPushToken,
    sound: 'default',
    title: 'Original Title',
    body: 'And here is the body!',
    data: { someData: 'goes here' },
  };

  await fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(message),
  });
}
```

So why does it work on the iPad, but not on the PC using the exact same token? By the way, I double-checked the token and tried the web based [push notifications tool](https://expo.io/notifications) and got a "This is not a valid Expo push token" error. Am I missing a step? I haven't done any actual build yet but thought it would just work.

Comment: How does the expo push token looks like? It should look like ExponentPushToken[*******************] I have used both using expo tool and curl, it worked fine for me. Try sending the CURL request using PHP code.

Comment: Yes, the token is in that format. I had left this for a while, but just tried again on the command line exactly as posted in the question and it worked, so I guess it must have been a temporary bug or glitch on the Expo side 3 months ago. If you want to post that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method shown in the question worked afterwards. The same `curl` command later returned `"status":"ok"` and I got the notification on the mobile device. This was likely a temporary issue on the Expo side.

If this happens again, and the API has not changed, the suggestion would be to try again later or contact Expo.